# How to unquote a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, quotes

If I quote a variable to prevent SQL injection as such:

```
$safe_email = $db->quote($_POST['email']);
```

If `$_POST['email']` = abc@example.com

and I do the following:

```
  echo $safe_email;
```

I get:

```
 "abc@example.com"
```

The [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) says that the `stripslashes` function "Un-quotes a quoted string".

However when I use it on my quoted string as such:

```
echo stripslashes($safe_email);
```

I still get the string printed out in quotes

What seems to be the problem here? It's still printing out in quotes

Comment: Parameterized queries: `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (?)"); $stmt->execute(array($_POST['email']));` Done.

Comment: Slashes and quotes aren't the same thing, why would a function called "strip slashes" remove quotation marks?

Comment: `stripslashes` removes slashes from (escaped) characters in a string.

Comment: @meagar The PHP Documentation clearly says "Un-quotes a quoted string"... is that not a quoted string?

Comment: That seems to be an unfortunate choice of words. It's certainly not the inverse of whatever your `quote` function does.

Comment: your right, that is a sucky piece of documentation

Comment: Well then what is the inverse of the `quote` function?

Comment: Why do you even have to worry about it if you use something like PDO to pass bound parameters? You can sanitize prior to binding if you wish.

Comment: Why are you going through these questions asking about how you can sanitize your inputs so that you can build SQL statements from outside data?  **Building SQL statements from outside data is dangerous.**

Rather than wasting your time worrying about how you can come up with another halfway thought out "solution", stop and put on your Big Programmer Pants and start using prepared statements and bound variables.

Here is a fantastic answer that will get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @kcdwayne Because I need to use the variable to display on a form... Just not with quotes

Comment: ...You can just pull the variable as a string from the database.. *how exactly are you sending/pulling data from your database?*

Comment: You guys need to take a chill... I only asked a question why get so bemused? It would be better to stick to my question rather than bring other things up... I would have asked if needed

Comment: I dont understand.. whats wrong with using `quote` it prevents SQL injection safe and sound

Comment: no it dosent, thats whats wrong with it

Comment: @Dagon Thanks... finally someone who can get to the point without beating around the bush

Comment: ... that's what we all.. nevermind.

Comment: I'm wondering how can i do the same but the OPPOSITE way - Insert a quote in a unquoted variable...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't necessarily a direct inverse of the `quote` function (assuming `PDO::quote` here). It surrounds the value by quotes and escapes special characters inside the string *to form a valid SQL string literal according to the underlying driver of the database*. And that may vary a bit from database to database and the specifics of your connection. You should also never need to unquote a string, because you're not supposed to use the quoted string in any other place but an SQL query:

```
sprintf('SELECT ... WHERE foo = %s', $pdo->quote($value))
```

There's no reason whatsoever to quote the value, and then unquote it again to use it anywhere else but an SQL query. Just use the original `$value` instead of the quoted value. And of course, you should be using prepared statements with bound parameters instead of manual quoting to begin with, so you should hardly have any reason to touch this function ever.

Having said that, this *should* cover most cases, though is far from guaranteed to always produce the correct result:

```
$unquoted = stripslashes(substr($quoted, 1, -1));
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with something like this?

`filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)`

Your question worries me. Please read up on PDO, bind your parameters, and rest easier at night. The road you seem to be traveling down is one of security risks, and will likely not end well.

*Side note: I like to sanitize both client side and server side, and bind parameters appropriately. Maybe I'm paranoid, but an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cures IMO.*

**Well since you don't seem to be interested in the *right* way**

`$email = str_replace('"','',$email);`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just want to remove quotation marks from the beginning and end of a string, and restore characters escaped with "\" in PHP. This is the intuitive meaning of "unquoting a string".

For example, the expression `var_export($value,true)` always single-quotes its result and escapes certain characters.

This expression will "unquote" such a string nicely: `stripslashes(substr(substr($str,1),0,-1))`.